# Is there a way to search for a non-repeating number in a sequence of numbers using Regex in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is what I have so far:

```
    import re
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        self.nums= nums
        string_nums= [str(num) for num in nums]
        string_nums= "".join(string_nums)
        string_nums.replace(',','')
        result= re.search(r"(^[,]?)([1-9]{1})?",string_nums).group()
        
        print(result)
```

If you recognize this question, please don't share the common answer, I am trying to figure this out using Regex.

Comment: "please don't share the answer" ... The purpose of all the Stack Exchange sites to share answers to questions.  I don't understand your comment.

Comment: The question has to do with a Leetcode question and has a common answer that I could just look up. I want to try to solve it differently using Regex, which is why I made that comment beforehand so that people don't direct me to or post that same answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, but you could use this solution.

```
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums: list[int]) -> int:
        self.nums= nums
        string_nums= [str(num) for num in nums]
        string_nums= "".join(string_nums)
        string_nums.replace(',','')
        distinct = [num for num in string_nums if string_nums.count(num) <= 1]
        result = "".join(distinct)

               
        print(result)
```